# Error al guardar datatimepicker en C# y mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Hola buenas tardes en esta ocación estoy realizando un ejercicio sencillo de guardar nombre, edad y fecha; el detalle radica que al guardar nombre y edad todo bien hasta ahi, el problema es que cuando le agrego el control datatimepicker y guardo arroja este error.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el codigo de mi clase.

```
public string insertar(string nombre,int edad, string fecha)
    {
       //MySqlCommand cmd;
        string salida = "Los datos se guardaron correctamente";
        try
        {
            cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO persona(nombre,edad,fecha) VALUES ('"+nombre+"',"+edad+","+fecha+")", Obtnerconexion());
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            salida = "No se conecto: " + ex.ToString();

        }
        return salida;
    }
```

y aqui les muestro el codigo de mi formulario para capturar el datatime

```
private void btnguardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    conn.conectar registro = new conn.conectar();
        MessageBox.Show(registro.insertar(txtnombre.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtedad.Text),dtpFecha.ToString()));
        conn.cargardatos carga = new conn.cargardatos();
        carga.CargarPersonas(dtgvpersonas);
        //funcion limpiar texbox
        conn.limpiar ltxt = new conn.limpiar();
        ltxt.BorrarCampos(this, groupBox1);

  }
```

Comment: Estas asignado el objeto Datetimepicker y no su valor. Seria  dtpFecha.Value. Te recomendaría enviarlo con formato a la base y no tendras problema con ningun idioma por el orden de día-mes, en sql server es .ToString("yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss"), 99% seguro que funcionara en mysql.

Comment: mi estimado Ramiro Barone gracias por el tips me sirvio como no tienes idea

Comment: @pablogervacio si la respuesta te parecio correcta, marcala como tal. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La excepción que te arroja es que estas asignando de forma equivocada el valor del `DateTimePicker`. Si debugeas te fijaras que valor le estas pasando que seguramente sera el texto del nombre del componente. Te dejo la linea para pasarle el valor de forma correcta
Por otro lado no es necesario que le hagas el `Convert.ToInt` al numero, ya que luego lo pasas como cadena.

```
  MessageBox.Show(registro.insertar(txtnombre.Text, Convert.ToInt32(txtedad.Text),dtpFecha.Value.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

como adicional al hacer tu toString(), lo que estas haciendo es trabajar sobre un objeto con lo que este no se convierte a string necesitas convertir el valor de tu objeto a string, ya te escribieron mas arriba el ejemplo.

Comment: de verdad  chavos muchisimas gracias por su ayuda saben la verdad me han salvado